# How to install node-opus with node-module-version 57

Tags: javascript, heroku, discord.js

I have been trying to use sound commands on my server but when I use them they don't work and it pops out this error:

```
Error: The module '/app/node_modules/node-opus/build/Release/node-opus.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
 at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:681:18)
 at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
 at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
 at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
 at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
 at bindings (/app/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
 at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/node-opus/lib/OpusEncoder.js:4:34)
 at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
```

I have never encountered this error and it works fine when I host it locally.

Comment: Have you tried running `npm rebuild` or `npm install` as suggested in the error?

Comment: @FedericoGrandi both of them give a make: cc: command not found error.